# flex connect to data http service of asp.net mvc4 web api show error on test InvocationTargetException:The URL is not valid

Tags: apache-flex, asp.net-web-api, httpservice, dataservice

I am trying to connect to Http Service using flex wizard
The server side is Asp.net MVC4 Web Api, I used the templates to create simple CRUD controller.
The problem is that test operation gives back: "InvocationTargetException:The URL is not valid" error message. I have seen that the problem is the http response status. If it is OK 200 then I dont have that problem. I can change the response status manually to OK in the controller, but why Flex cannot handle the default 204 response status from controller template?

This is the function from the server controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Postattributes(attributes attributes)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.attributes.Add(attributes);
        db.SaveChanges();
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, attributes);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = attributes.attId }));
        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }
}
```

if I change to HttpStatusCode.OK I do not get the error